# How do I call a method in Kotlin with a different upper bound?

Tags: kotlin

e.g. Given a `Class<T>` how do I call/invoke a method/constructor that requires `Class<T> where T : Enum<T>`?

```
fun <T : Any> handleAny(classOfT: Class<T>) {
    if (classOfT.isEnum) {
        handleEnum(classOfT)
    }
}

fun <T : Enum<T>> handleEnum(classOfT: Class<T>) { /*...*/ }
```

Error: `inferred type T is not a subtype of kotlin.Enum<T>`

In Java I can do an unchecked call but I cannot seem to find a way to do anything similar in Kotlin.

Comment: FYI: In addition to hotkey's great workaround below I've created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12393.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for now I found this quite hacky workaround for it:

```
private enum class DummyEnum    

fun <T> handleAny(classOfT: Class<T>) {
    if (classOfT.isEnum) {
        handleEnum(classOfT as Class<DummyEnum>) //absolutely any enum goes
    }
}

fun <T : Enum<T>> handleEnum(classOfT: Class<T>) {
    println(classOfT.toString())
}
```

The idea is to make an unchecked cast to the type with any generic parameter satisfying the upper bound (let it be `DummyEnum`), which will then be erased at runtime anyway.

The limitation is that the solution **doesn't work correctly with reified generics**: if `handleEnum` had reified type parameter, it would be substituted for statically inferred type (`DummyEnum`).